# Is there a way to detect if the selection panel on a md-autocomplete material2+angular2 is being shown?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to detect if the panel is being shown or not but from the documentations, I can't seem to figure out what to use that will correctly tell me which property would trigger the right event.

If anyone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`md-autocomplete` has a property called `showPanel`. You can return the value of `showPanel` using the `#` reference of autocomplete.

Here's an example, for every `keyup` event in the input field, I check the value of `showPanel` and push it to an array for verifying if it works.

html:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="State" 
         [mdAutocomplete]="auto" 
         [formControl]="stateCtrl"
         (keyup)="checkPanel(auto.showPanel)">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
    {{ state }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>

<p></p>

<div style="margin-top: 300px">
  <span>Is panel open at keyup:</span>
  <div *ngFor="let x of flags; let i = index">
    keyup {{i+1}}: {{x}}
  </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
checkPanel(val){
  this.flags.push(val);
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gCk2IfIz4zec56TgSo9x?p=preview)